# Making UITableViewCell from Nib

Tags: swift, nib, uitableview

I'm trying create UITableViewCell from Nib.
So my xib. file looks like:

[image]

How change height of each row of my tableView depends of content size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at great tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells
Its for autolayout-way. But delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //code
}
```

is much more preferred cause its REAL faster. Look here: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.i439tyds6

Comment: Thanks a lot! Answer at SOF awesome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930